# Should two separate COM devices be placed into the same thread?

Tags: user-interface, io, controller, device, motion

I'm looking to control a motion controller with a joystick. Should I place the Joystick in the same thread as the motion controller or place it in its own thread?

Currently I have a UI that send requests to a thread containing the motion controller's request manager. I use a system of queues to safely transfer data.

In the past I have made an application where all the devices had their own thread. The project quickly became clunky and messy. I am new to working with hardware. I would greatly appreciate any references or books suggestions.